# Quiero sacar un reporte en odoo15 desde el menú

Tags: python, odoo, reporte

Cuando imprimo el siguiente reporte en Odoo15 desde el menu no me sale el reporte, la función se ejecuta porque al hacer debug entra  en la función e incluso imprime valores si se los pongo pero no me imprime el reporte en html como se lo estoy pidiendo, simplemente se queda en la vista y no hace nada, si cambio el reporte a qweb-pdf es lo mismo no hace nada

Este es el menú item

```
<menuitem   id="menu_1"
                name="My report menu name"
                parent="my_module.parent_menu"
                action="action_1"
                sequence="3"/>
```

Este es el action

```
<record id="action_1" model="ir.actions.server">
        <field name="name">Name</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.server</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="model_mymodel"/>
        <field name="binding_type">report</field>
        <field name="help">Helper</field>
        <field name="state">code</field>
        <field name="code">model.action_print_report()</field>
    </record>
```

Esta la función del modelo

```
@api.model    
def action_print_report(self):
    
    
    datas={'print':"This is working"}
    
    return_report_action = self.env.ref('my_module.report_1').report_action([], data=datas)
    
    return_report_action['close_on_report_download']=True   #close wizard if report is qweb-pdf
    return return_report_action
```

Y este el reporte

```
<record id="report_1" model="ir.actions.report">
                <field name="name">Name</field>
                <field name="model">mymodel</field>
                <field name="report_type">qweb-html</field> 
                <field name="report_name">my_module.report_1_template</field>
                <field name="report_file">my_module.report_1_template</field>
                <field name="print_report_name">My report name</field>
                <field name="binding_type">report</field>
        </record>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que devolver una accion a un parametro "magico" de odoo llamado "action"

```xml
<field name="code">action = model.action_print_report()</field>
```

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración, la verdad ese action es magico, las cosas de odoo :)

Comment: Ni que lo digas...